# How to compute LPWSTR size when using GetDlgItemText()  function

Tags: c++, winapi

My request is small
I am using **`GetDlgItem()`** to get text from a text field , but I have a problem in the fourth parameter (i.e. size of buffer) .

```
LPWSTR txtbuff;
GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1, txtbuff, 50); // the fourth parameter (50)
MessageBox(NULL,txtbuff,L"Error message",MB_OK)
```

How can I compute size of **`txtbuff`**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [GetDlgItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the control's HWND and [GetWindowTextLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine how many characters are held by your control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate a buffer yourself:

```
WCHAR txtbuff[50];
GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1, txtbuff, 50);
/* or... */
GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1, txtbuff, sizeof(textbuff)/sizeof(textbuff[0]));
MessageBox(NULL, txtbuff, L"Error message", MB_OK);
```

A simple `LPWSTR` variable is a pointer, in your example, you have a pointer, but it doesn't point anywhere yet.  By creating the buffer explicitly, you specify the size, and can provide it to `GetDlgItem`.

Comment: The problem is determine the characters, because I don't know their number when a user input the value.

Comment: @Lion King maybe you not understand that memory needs to be allocated before.If you need to know length of user's input, use GetWindowTextLength

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sizeof` like so:

```
TCHAR txtbuff[50];
GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1, txtbuff, sizeof(txtbuff) * sizeof(TCHAR));
```

Comment: In your code, you have added a specific number [50], and I don't know what's the number of character

Comment: Sorry, but you need to know maximal length of buffer in advance for use with GetDlgItemText.In your code you use LPWSTR, which is pointer to WCHAR, so memory needs to be allocated before.

Comment: Not true. You can ask the control how big the buffer needs to be to fit the whole text.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but it means that you get size in advance before real call of GetDlgItemText.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the size of the buffer. It is the amount of the string you actually want to copy. You could set it to any non zero size you want in theory. The size of your own buffer on the other hand is a different story, just make sure you dont overflow.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I mean number of characters in string